# Alignment improvement in the flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, flag-dialog

When I flagged a post, before it was closed if I click the "flag" link I can see which flag type I selected for the post in the flag dialog.

The selected flag type is shown as "This is the flag you currently have raised". The text is not indented with any of the content.

As I know the usage of seeing this screen is very less, but can this text be improved?

[image]

Comment: Looks like simply changing the `margin-left` CSS property on `.popup .already-flagged` from 16px to 23px would fix this. The description above it has a 5px margin and 18px of padding, for a total of 5 + 18 = 23 pixels.  I've no idea where that 16px might have come from, since it doesn't seem to match anything. Maybe from some older flag popup design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the alignment is fine now. It has proper indent and padding. Seems it was fixed recently.

Adding the recent screen shot.

[image: ss]